# Composite function simple question

Tags: functions

Can you help me with an example?

I have to find a composite function that answers:

1) Define a function $f$ and a function $g$ such that $f (g(x)) = f (x) g (x)$.

I tried to find functions that are derived, but it did not work. (I know the trivial examples of $f(x)=1=g(x)$ and $f(x)=0$, and I am looking for more interesting examples.)

Comment: A boring example would be $f=0$.

Comment: $f(x) = g(x) = 1$

Comment: I had thought of these trivial cases

Comment: If you thought of those "trivial cases" and tried to find "more interesting examples", please share your attempts so Readers can better judge what you found difficult or interesting.  In particular you ought to have given some consideration to what restrictions you are willing to place on the domain and range of the functions, i.e. so that composition and product are defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Nice use of $2*2 = 2+2$

Comment: that's what I'm talking about! thank you

Comment: No problem! I'm glad to help! @MuradinBronzebeard